# embark-collect-* showing wrong number of arguements from Selectrum

Tags: minibuffer

I've been trying to get Selectrum, Embark and other packages working together as a completion framework, but am running into a problem with `embark-collect-snapshot` (and `embark-collect-live`).

In the minibuffer, using selectrum, when I run the command `embark-collect-snapshot` I get the error

```
Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 2), 10
```

I've tinkered a bit but don't really know how to solve, or diagnose, the problem.

To recreate the issue you can follow the following steps:

1. Create new .emacs.d directory with the following `init.el` file:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 27)
  (package-initialize))

;; Bootstrap 'use-package'
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))


(use-package selectrum
  :ensure t
  :demand t
  :config
  (selectrum-mode t))

(use-package embark
  :ensure t
  :demand t
  :bind (("C-," . embark-act)
         :map selectrum-minibuffer-map
         ("C-," . embark-act)
         ("C->" . embark-become)))
```

2. Open emacs
3. Evoke a function that opens up a Selectrum completion list (for example `C-x b`)
4. Run `embark-act` with `C-,`
5. Choose `embark-collect-snapshot` with `S`

Other info:

```
GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-06, modified by Debian

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate question. There are a lot of questions dealing with that error message. Please search for that error message, and if you find a duplicate question then please delete this one. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in the embark package, which has now been fixed by the maintainer.